# Hello LLVM pass not loading

Tags: macos, llvm

I am following the Hello pass tutorial for LLVM, running on OSX Lion. I got as far as make in the `lib/Transforms/Hello` directory, create the bitcode, and then did this in the Hello directory:

```
$ opt -load ../../../Debug/lib/LLVMHello.dylib -hello < hello.bc > /dev/null
opt: <stdin>: Unknown instruction
```

I tried to search for this but did not find anything. Any suggestions?

I am not sure if this matters, but I am using gcc 4.2.1.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that your llvm-gcc and LLVM are out of synch / incompatible. With wrong LLVM even simple `lli` will fail:

```
$ lli hello.bc 
lli: hello.bc: Unknown instruction
```

You can either fetch the LLVM corresponding to your compiler or use a compiler based on your LLVM. For the former you can get the tag using `--version`, e.g.:

```
$ llvm-gcc-4.2 --version
i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc.
build 5658) (LLVM build 2335.15.00)
```

means that you can get the corresponding LLVM from

```
http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/llvm/tags/Apple/llvmCore-2335.15
```

Once you get the matching LLVM all is well:

```
$ Debug/bin/lli hello.bc 
hello world
$ Debug/bin/opt -load Debug/lib/LLVMHello.dylib -hello <hello.bc  >/dev/null
Hello: main
```